# A Way To Reset All Timers

Tags: javascript, timer, reset

My question is: is there a unique way to reset timers without knowing their ID in Javascript? I tried using this code:

```
var maxId = setTimeout(function(){}, 0);

for(var i=0; i < maxId; i+=1) { 
    clearTimeout(i);
}
```

I'm aware this would search for any timer and clear any timer, but nothing happens and I think the console even gives me an error when I use it as a bookmarklet. Also, the value of the timer is stored in innerHTML, as such:

```
<div id="timer">

    <div id="timer-minutes" class="timer-fields">00:00</div>

</div>
```

Comment: While your code should basically work, you likely have to manage them by yourself. There are several libraries that do that, Google them.

Comment: Store them in an array.

Comment: I don't understand what this for loop is supposed to do. Just to be clear, the return value from `setTimeout` isn't some sort of upper limit (you're stopping just short of it in your iteration anyway). It's just a value you can pass to `clearTimeout` to clear the timeout prematurely.

Comment: Does it make a difference if the timer is incrementing, not decrementing? Because I tried using an array method to no avail --- javascript:var timers = new Array();

// add a timer to the array
timers.push(setTimeout('someFunc()', 1000));

// clear all timers in the array
for (var i = 0; i < timers.length; i++)
{
    clearTimeout(timers[i]);
}

Comment: If you change `< maxId` to `<= maxId` then nothing should be fired. The way your code works now, it invalidates all of the previous timers.

Comment: And what do you mean by "I think the console even gives me an error when I use it as a bookmarklet", it either does or it does not. ;)

Comment: It doesn't but it changes nothing. What if the timer is stored in a variable? How would I go about resetting it's value through a bookmarklet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A unique way to look at this problem is to override the default functionality of setTimeout. By augmenting the function you can then tap into all uses of setTimeout on the page.  Then you can simply create a new method to clear all timeouts.

In the code below, I hot-wire the built-in function (setTimeout) with my own version. As long as this code executes before other scripts on the page, I then can keep track of all invocations of the function on the page.  Perhaps you could even store the setTimeouts by callee.

```
(function(win)
{
  var _originalSetTimeout = setTimeout; //Store built-in function
  var timers = []; //Maintain a collection of timers

  win.setTimeout = function(func, delay) //Hijack the built-in function with your own
  {
    var timer = _originalSetTimeout(func, delay); //Invoke the built in
    timers.push(timer);  //Store the timer to your private array
  };

  win.clearAllTimeouts = function()  //Create a new function on the window for resetting all timers
  {
    for(var i=0,length=timers.length;i<length;i++)
      {
        win.clearTimeout(timers[i]);
      }
  };
}(window));
```

Once this function is wired up you then can test with the following code:

```
var x=0;
function Test()
{
  x++;
  console.log('test: ' + x);
  setTimeout(Test, 1000);

  if(x === 5)
  {
    clearAllTimeouts();
    console.log('all timeouts cleared!');
  }
}
Test();
```

The counter will log up to 5, then once it's it the clearAllTimeouts() function is invoked.

See it in action here:
http://jsbin.com/bulayuro/1/edit